# What's the correct way to set a base REM value in CSS?

Tags: css

Sorry, I'm a little unsure of this.

I want my base to be 16px. But all the resources I read about rem use percentages, eg:

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; } 
body { font-size: 1.4rem; } /* =14px */
h1   { font-size: 2.4rem; } /* =24px */
```

If I want all my rem sizes to be relative to 16px, do I just make `html { font-size: 16px; }`?

Why use percentages?

Comment: yes it's right. You need to make your html/body `font-size` to `16px` as your base font-size and then use rem with the rest

Comment: @Ron.Basco Thanks! Want to make that an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

yes that's right. You need to make your html `font-size` to `16px` as your base font-size and then use `rem` with the rest. `Rem` sizes the element relative only to `html` while `em` sizes relatively to its nearest parent.

Comment: Be careful with this. If you set the font-size property on the html tag (such as `html {font-size:10px;`), it will disable the browser override for font size.