# How to decease or increase sizes in CSS all togther?

Tags: html, css

I'm coding for a responsive website using basic CSS and HTML(without bootstrap).
now I wanna change the size of elements(caption font, picture size, etc) to be set up for size of various devices.
for example I have codes like below:

```
.footer-link{
font-size: 14px;
width: 80%;
padding-bottom: 20px;}
```

and want to reduce **10%** of sizes by a code to have sth like:

```
 .footer-link{
font-size: 12px;
width: 72%;
padding-bottom: 18px;}
```

I know about **media** . but with that I still need to rewrite every single code and size in each media! Actually i want to avoid rewriting by having some especial code that reduces all sizes in a media itself alone.

but I don't have any idea of doing this.

any recommendation please?

Comment: You will need to use media queries.

Comment: Css media queries are the way

Comment: The `em` unit is used this way. In your case `0.9em` would be `90%` of the base font-size. https://css-tricks.com/why-ems/

Comment: @Tank I would agreee with your comment but would rewrite with the more useful `rem`

Answer (score 2):

you can add `@media` query in css and add the max width in which the inner code will be vaild. for example:

```
@media  (max-width: 600px) {
 .footer-link{
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 72%;
    padding-bottom: 18px;}
}
```

now only when the device have maximum width of 600px this code will be executed.

Also you can change the size to make it `em`,`rem`, `vw`, `vh`, `%` instead of normal `px` preoperty to make it more dynamic.

you can read more about how to make responsive website [from here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

Comment: I know about media . but I still need to rewrite every single code and size in each media! Actually i want to avoid rewriting by having some especial code that reduces all sizes in a media itself alone

Comment: Yup you need to rerwitre your code, css doesn't know how it should behave in various screen sizes, So that, I've mentioned alternative  ways to define your sizes insteasd of `px`

Comment: Kareem Dabbeet yeah I got it just now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for a small device:

```
.footer-link{
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 80%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .footer-link{
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 72%;
  padding-bottom: 18px;}
}
```

to do other sizes you just create a new media query and change the size, bootstrap 4's breakpoints look like this:

```
xs = Extra small <576px.
sm = Small ≥576px. 
md = Medium ≥768px.
lg = Large ≥992px. 
xl = Extra large ≥1200px.
```

Answer (score 0):

Three methods:

## ONE:

**1) Use the `rem` scaling measurement**

Do NOT use `px`, instead use the [`rem` scaling measurement](https://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing/). `rem` is **Root em** and everything works from this *:root* value, this hiarachy is critical for step 2:

**2) Use `@media` queries to control the root-`em` size**

Once set, you can run a media query simply controlling the *root*-em (`rem`) value for each of your `@media` queries.

**Example:**

```
:root {
    font-size: 16px; /* this sets 1rem */ 
}
.footer-link{
    font-size: 0.9rem; /* 16 x 0.9 */
    width: 5rem;
    padding-bottom: calc(100% - 5rem);
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px){
    :root {
        /* Everything is magically a bit smaller */
        font-size: 14px; 
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Setting `font-size:` in the `html{ ... }` can maybe [overwrite the browser font-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372752/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-a-base-rem-value-in-css#comment79580694_40373190) setting (*unconfirmed by me*).

---

## TWO:

Using **ONE** above but also with [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) for ease of adjustment.

**Exampe:**

```
:root {
   /* percentage */
   --widthValue: 80%; 
   font-size: 16px; /* this is still needed as sets 1rem */ 
}

.footer-link{
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: var(--widthValue);
    padding-bottom: calc(100% - var(--widthValue));
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px){
    :root {
        /* Everything is magically a bit smaller */
        font-size: 15px;
        --widthValue: 76%; 
    }
}
```

This allows you to fine tweak adjustments that can not easily be scoped by `rem` values.  Read [more here](https://codepen.io/Yuschick/post/getting-dynamic-with-css-variables-media-queries).

---

## THREE:

There was a third method in my mind when I started writing this answer but I think the two above should between them more than easily cover what you're looking for.

> I know about media . but I still need to rewrite every single code and size in each media

Yes, you will need to update your basic CSS as written in your question, but that's inevitable as you're replacing *static* code with *varaible* driven code.

The solution I present is **D**ont **R**epeat **Y**ourself ([huh?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) -- you only need to change one value in the `@media` query and all the styles *cascade* from that one simple change.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code you provided is not a sample of responsive website. To be responsive we have to redesign and reorder elements. Some elements like images and backgrounds may need to be resized but the **fonts**, **widths** and **paddings** etc. should not be smaller when the screen is smaller. For example if you reduce the width of elements when the window is smaller in a small window you have nothing rather than elements with `width:1%` !

So I think you need a kind of **ZOOM** which may be appropraite for games and somethings special.

Besides without using CSS media queries and without rewriting css rules, the only way to zoom everything is JS codes. So I write simple sample to show how you can zoom everything according to the window size.

**Please try resizing the window  to check the effect:**

```js
var myDesignWidth=500; //this is the initial width which you design everything


$(window).on("load resize",function(){
   var newZoom=$(window).width() / myDesignWidth;
   $("body").css({"zoom":newZoom});
})
```

```css
.footer-link{
font-size: 14px;
width: 80%;
padding-bottom: 20px;
display:inline-block;
background:url('https://d1o2pwfline4gu.cloudfront.net/m/t/13116/13106367/a-0270.jpg');
background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="footer-link">This is a footer link with background</a>
```